# Can I change the controls for Super Mario 64?

Tags: super-mario-64

I'm finding it difficult to play super Mario with the analog joystick. Is there any way that I can turn it off and just use the d-pad on the left of the controller instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nintendo 64 controller options](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/232356/nintendo-64-controller-options)

Comment: @Nolonar the questions are related, and are posted by the same person. However, the other question is more general, while this one is specific to the game "Super Mario 64".

Comment: Are you using an emulator? If so, which one.

Comment: Even if you could do this, it would provide a disadvantage in some stages.  One feature of the analog stick is that the the amount of tilt allows for different movement speeds, and there are areas where being able to walk instead of run is very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

No. Like most Nintendo 64 games, there's no option to use the D-pad. It had no function in Super Mario 64. If you're not playing on an actual Nintendo 64, however, you may have other options.

As an aside, Super Mario 64 DS for the Nintendo DS is a remake of the original game which can use the D-pad for movement. Note that it's not the exact same game, but they are very similar experiences.

Comment: Dpad had functionality in my game..

Comment: @Timelord64 I'm not sure what to make of your comment. For Super Mario 64 played on an actual Nintendo 64, the D-pad simply has no function whatsoever, and I have multiple sources - plus the fact that I just pulled it out and tried it - backing me up. If you're talking about the original game, you are unquestionably mistaken. If you're talking about playing on an emulator, or Virtual Console, or Super Mario 64 DS, those are different circumstances, and not covered by the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Weird. I recall using the d-pad to alter the camera in my version. Manual doesn't make reference to having camera control.

Comment: @Timelord64 Nope, it's the C-buttons that were used to control the camera. They were arranged in a D-pad sort of shape, and considering how little it was used, I suppose it could be easy to forget the N64 had an actual D-pad too and get them confused or something.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Poor left-side-of-the-n64-controller.